# Export org-protocol links to html

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-protocol

In the process of exporting Org files to html, I would like an org-protocol link in Org mode to export to html using the html export backend.

In my Org file, my org-protocol link is styled like this:

```
[[org-protocol://open-file?file=/Users/user/Download/test.org][Link to test file]]
```

`org-protocol://open-file` is a custom protocol as defined in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52085/have-an-org-protocol-that-opens-a-file-and-moves-point-to-it).

This should export to html like this:

```
<a href="org-protocol://open-file?file=/Users/user/Download/test.org">Link to test file</a>
```

When I test conversion to html using `org-html-convert-region-to-html`, I get the error `Unable to resolve link: "org-protocol://open-file?file=/Users/user/Download/test.org"`.

System information: Emacs 27.2, Org mode 9.4.4, MacOS 12.2.1.

How can I export my `org-protocol` link to html?

Comment: Does the link in the Org file actrually work? If you click on it, does the file open? I get an error saying `"No match for fuzzy expression: org-protocol://open..."`.

Comment: It doesn't work in the org file, but the HTML code works in a webpage. I've tested `org-protocol` by putting the example HTML link in an HTML source block, which exports correctly and functions as expected. I guess I forgot to mention that `org-protocol://open-file` is a custom protocol, that I've defined using [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52085/have-an-org-protocol-that-opens-a-file-and-moves-point-to-it). My initial asssumption was that getting `org-protocol` links to work properly in Org was a separate problem from exporting them to HTML, but it could be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `org-protocol` to `org-link-parameters`, as suggested by [this solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24128/custom-behaviour-when-exporting-links-org-export?rq=1) and [this solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35892/properly-formatting-outlook-links-in-org-html-export).

Having this code in my `init.el` fixed my problem:

```
(org-link-set-parameters
 "org-protocol"
 :export (lambda (path desc backend)
       (cond
        ((eq 'html backend)
         (format "<a href=\"org-protocol:%s\">%s</a>" path desc)))))
```

It's likely that one could fix the error mentioned in NickD's comment by setting the `:follow` parameter for `"org-protocol"` in a similar way, but that's not related to the original question about exporting links.